# Using spread() in R with variable column names

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I would like to use the spread function, but with column names that change depending on the function.  I have tried options that work with select(), to no avail.  Here are my failed attempts:

```
use_spread <- function(df, colname1, colname2)
{
  ...
  out = df %>% spread(colname1, colname2)
  out = df %>% spread(as.name(colname1), as.name(colname2))
  out = df %>% spread(match(c(colname1, colname2), colnames(.)))
  ...
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html)

Comment: spread_() is to be used whenever you want a column name as character

Comment: So simple, thanks!  Using spread_(colname1, colname2) works exactly as desired.